# How to remove Headers and Footers programmatically in IE while printing, instead of using IE Page Setup?

Tags: internet-explorer, printing, installation, header, footer

How to remove Headers and Footers programmatically in IE while printing, instead of using IE Page Setup?

Comment: **What have you tried?** (emboldening all the text in your question makes it [feel rather shouty](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Please_don%27t_shout)).

Comment: @WaiHaLee Sorry i was not aware of that.

Comment: no problem. What *have* you tried?

Comment: I have tried CSS @media print but that is for within our code. I have no idea how to disable this IE headers and footers programmatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Answer from microsoft:*

Users can easily change page margins, header and footer settings, and the default Internet Explorer printer through the Internet Explorer user interface. However, **there are no methods under Internet Explorer or the WebBrowser control to change these settings programmatically**.

You cannot use the ExecWB command to set page margins and the header or footer. These values are stored in the registry.

There might be a need to change the print settings of Internet Explorer or the WebBrowser control programmatically. The only settings that can be changed are page margins, and header and footer information. There is no supported way to change other settings like page orientation or printer.

Important This section, method, or task contains steps that tell you how to modify the registry. However, serious problems might occur if you modify the registry incorrectly. Therefore, make sure that you follow these steps carefully. For added protection, back up the registry before you modify it. Then, you can restore the registry if a problem occurs. For more information about how to back up and restore the registry, click the following article number to view the article in the Microsoft Knowledge Base:
322756 How to back up and restore the registry in Windows

This is how Microsoft Internet Explorer accesses the printing settings:

For Page Margins, Microsoft Internet Explorer first tries to get the values from this registry key:
**HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\PageSetup**
If there is no such a key, Internet Explorer create this key by copying the values from the following:
**HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\PageSetup**
If there is no such key, default values are provided.

For the Header and Footer, the values are picked up from the following:
**HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\PageSetup**
If there is no such key, default values are provided.

The defaults are 0.75 for margins,

For the Internet Explorer default printer, default values are provided from:
**HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\PageSetup\printer**
The developer could alter the above registry entries for the printing settings accordingly.

Please note that these values are system-wide and affect all instances of the WebBrowser control and Internet Explorer for the current user.

**So:**
I think you can offer users run your .reg file. (feautiful decision for legendary IE)